# how to pick specific element in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I need to pick up the clicked item from a list, my input is like below:

```
item_arr=tf.constant([['item001', 'item010', 'item020', 'item030', 'item041', 'item051'], 
                      ['item101', 'item110', 'item120', 'item130', 'item140', 'item151']])
clicked_arr=tf.constant([[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

the `item_arr` is batch data of items, and `clicked_arr` is clicked flag(1 is clicked, 0 is no clicked) corresponding to `item_arr`.

I hope to get the output that pick up the clicked items like that:

```
clicked_item_arr(for example, output shape is [2,4]):
[
['item001', 'item041', 'item051', 'item_placeholder'], 
['item101', 'item151', 'item_placeholder', 'item_placeholder']
]
```

I also need to get to no-clicked items but the same solution of clicked items should be used.

I tried to use `gather_nd` and `sparse_to_dense`:

```
index_arr=tf.where(tf.equal(clicked_arr, 1))
>>> array([[0, 0],
       [0, 4],
       [0, 5],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 5]])
sparse_item_value= tf.gather_nd(item_arr, index_arr)
>>> array(['item001', 'item041', 'item051', 'item101', 'item151'],
      dtype=object)
```

but I can't get the result I want, because I need sparse_indices like:

```
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1]])
```

so that I can use:

```
tf.sparse_to_dense(
    sparse_indices=sparse_indices,
    sparse_values=sparse_item_value,
    output_shape=[2, 10],
    default_value='item_placeholder'
)
```

But I don't know how to get the sparse_indices. Hope you can give me some advice and thanks in advance.

Comment: `index_arr` can be used as `sparse_indices`

Comment: @NicolasGervais I'm not very familiar with TF, can you give me some detail more? thank in advance.